# Error occured while running .NetCore application

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a dotnet core webapplication. When i run the application in debug mode , i get the following error :

```
An error occured attempting to determine the process id of the *.web.exe which 
is hosting your application. One or more errors occured.  
Dot net version installed in the machine
```

What is the solution for this?

Following are the readings :

a) Dotnet version installed in the machine

```
 dotnet --version
 1.0.0-preview2-003121
```

And

by runnnig dotnet

```
Microsoft .Net Core Shared Framework Host: 
Version : 1.0.1
Build : some alphanumeric value
```

WebConfig settings are :

```
 <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" 
 forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
 stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout" />
```

And Global.Json is :

```
"sdk": {
"version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"
}
```

Comment: Do you run your website on SSL?

Comment: @koelkastfilosoof : I am not sure. This is my iis express setting in launchSettings.json                                                                                        "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://****:55346/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }

Comment: @koelkastfilosoof : How do i check the SSL setting. could you give me pointers

Comment: How do you run your application? In IIS Express or Kestrel?

Comment: @koelkastfilosoof : Running it in Kestrel works fine for it. It asked for a permission to run Dotnetcore.exe for the first time and runs fine after words. Seems like while i was running using IISExpress , it could not get the permission to run dotnetcore. Problem is fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: Right, yeah you might need to run Visual Studio as Administrator for IISExpress. I'm using Kestrel most of the time and it works fine for me. Have a look at this issue, it might have some relation to yours: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1608

Comment: Why are you still using Preview 2? Can you update to the latest released version of .Net Core?